# Handling OverflowError: math range error in Python with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling, cmath

I have the following code in Python

```
z =  [[complex(x,y) for x in range(1000)]for y in range(1000)]
nexp = np.frompyfunc(cmath.exp,1,1)
nexp(z)
```

I have OverflowError: math range error.

Is there any way to find which elements of array rises error and handle it?
I mean if I simply iterate through array I could make it that way

```
for x in range(1000):
    for y in range(1000):
        try:
            z[x,y] = cmath.exp(z[x,y])
        except:
            z[x,y] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use numpy types and methods instead of `complex` and `cmath`?

Demo:

```
In [302]: x = np.arange(701, 720) + 1j*np.arange(701, 720)

In [303]: y = np.exp(x)
~\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\py36\Scripts\ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
```

this yields:

```
In [304]: y
Out[304]:
array([ -2.51188899e+304 -1.13634915e+304j,  -1.08996190e+304 -7.41453166e+304j,   1.53588478e+305 -1.33828078e+305j,   5.31686829e+305 +1.5
4758929e+305j,   4.26896569e+305 +1.44345018e+306j,
        -2.67470300e+306 +3.09645066e+306j,  -1.10110029e+307 -1.57025773e+306j,  -1.25800559e+307 -2.74923036e+307j,   4.44084142e+307 -6.9
1528370e+307j,               inf +1.34684655e+304j,
                     inf             +infj,              -inf             +infj,              -inf             +infj,              -inf
        -infj,               inf             -infj,
                     inf             -infj,               inf             +infj,              -inf             +infj,              -inf
        +infj])
```

all infinite elements:

```
In [305]: y[np.isinf(y)]
Out[305]:
array([ inf +1.34684655e+304j,  inf             +infj, -inf             +infj, -inf             +infj, -inf             -infj,  inf
    -infj,  inf             -infj,  inf             +infj,
       -inf             +infj, -inf             +infj])
```

index of the first infinite element:

```
In [306]: np.isinf(y).argmax()
Out[306]: 9
```

Comment: I don't use numpy methods as want to have more general approach as I want to use special libraries like mpmath with functions which are not provided with numpy, for example Elliptic and Zeta functions